# How can I do to create array multi dimensions with string as indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Hello I wondering how can I do to to this :

```
a["Hello"]["Test"]["Sun"] = 3
```

I tried like this but it does not work.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are coming from a language like PHP. In Python arrays (or lists as they are called in Python) cannot have string indices, but you can use a dictionary for this.

To make assigning items work using that type of syntax `a["Hello"]["Test"]` must already exist as a dictionary, and that requires `a["Hello"]` to exist as a dictionary, etc.

```
a = {}
a["Hello"] = {}
a["Hello"]["Test"] = {}
a["Hello"]["Test"]["Sun"] = 3
```

But you can do it all at once like this.

```
a = {'Hello': {'Test': {'Sun': 3}}}
```

Or a combination of the two.

```
a = {}
a["Hello"] = {'Test': {'Sun': 3}}
```